# Calling a list of functions and applying to one argument scheme

Tags: scheme

Is there a simple way to make it if i wanted to run several test on that one argument to do so? Like ‘(add1 list? number? square) 3) and get (4 #f #t 9)?

(define (construct(functList argv))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` over the function list, applying each one to the value:

```
(define (f-map fns v)
  (map (lambda (f) (f v)) fns))

> (f-map (list add1 list? number?) 3)
'(4 #f #t)
```